# WCF - Is GetCallbackChannel reliable?

Tags: c#, wcf

In the part "**Figure 5 Storing the Callback References for Later Use**" of [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/october/wcf-working-with-one-way-calls-callbacks-and-events), it's clear that the service would need to keep the manual cache list synchronized reflecting the connected clients only to prevent exceptions caused by the reference to old clients that got disconnected. But, if I don't plan to use such a cache mechanism (for which I don't see any need at all) and I directly access `GetCallbackChannel<T>` instead to perform event calls to the client, is it guaranteed that the internal list will **<s>only contain all connected clients and would</s>** never throw a corresponding `CommunicationException` when calling a contained event?

Comment: There are few guarantees in this world, and even less when it comes to sockets. Catch handle and move on... Though you should really be moving away from WCF and to more modern technologies

Comment: There are no guarantees, even if there were, by the time you read it, what to say a client hasn't disconnected, or suffered a network failure? As to the second part of my comment which you seem to have focused on, the advice was tendered, and its good advice. take it or leave it. Good luck

Comment: @TheGeneral If you could read between lines you'd understand the question point wasn't about strictly ensuring the first part of the condition. You're right a client might disconnected without sending any notification to the service (not sure if WCF even acknowledges connection closes) right before calling them back by a separate thread (the "event"), which I hadn't realized. The point is to get the knowledge on whether even under that circumstance an exception would be thrown or not, naturally (which is the interest of the programmer). Updated question now to make it clearer.

Comment: Reliability requires a comparison. GetCallbackChannel property can obtain a channel that you can use to call operations on the client instance that called the service.

Comment: @Jiayao Thanks for your comment, which led me to investigate by my own again. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I hadn't read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.getcallbackchannel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) where it says:

> Gets a channel to the client instance that called the current
> operation.

This immediately causes the "**Figure 5 Storing the Callback References for Later Use**" part of the [first tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/october/wcf-working-with-one-way-calls-callbacks-and-events) to make sense now, as we'll call the clients (supporting multiple in fact) in another thread (so deferred to their requests). I thought `GetCallbackChannel` simply represented the whole acknowledged callbacks (one per client) at any point of the service execution.

I understand then I'll naturally have to catch exceptions such as `CommunicationException` once I mimic that caching list approach (or simply `Exception` only).